# Is there a convention for making notes while developing an app on android studios

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm making an app right now and I make notes on paper about what I am doing. Sometimes it can be a log of what I have done or what I need to do. Other times I just jot down my thoughts so I can look at them and organize them. Is there a convention for including this logging process in the project in android studios? For now, I'm going to make a devlog.txt file <sub>(or a text file in a new log directory)</sub> in the app directory of the project.

Answer (score 1):

> Sometimes it can be a log of what I have done or what I need to do.

What you have done should be captured by your source control tool - i.e., GIT.

What you have to do should be captured by your to-do app - i.e., a physical notebook, Todoist, Trello, etc, etc, etc.

> Is there a convention for including this logging process in the project in android studios?

No - "how to capture your thoughts" is an extremely personal and subjective problem. Do what works for you.

> For now, I'm going to make a devlog.txt file (or a text file in a new log directory) in the app directory of the project.

OK - that sounds as good a solution as any.

Answer (score 0):

Use the TODO flag throughout your code to remind you to do something later, such as adding functionality or fixing a bug:

```
// TODO: fix bug
```

It will highlight that line of text in blue to make it more visible, as well as give you the ability to view all TODO's throughout your code by clicking on the TODO item on the bottom bar of Android Studio.

These TODOs can span multiple lines, just be sure to add the `//` before each line.

Comment: Oh ya, that to-do functionality is neat. But isn't to do just one line. I want to be able to make multi-lined notes. For instance, I am going to write 2 similar classes that aggregate stuff. So I wanted to jot down similarities differences to check if I should consider making one a subclass of the other or making them siblings or something else.  I'm not sure I an meke these notes in to-do.

Comment: Updated the answer to call out that these TODOs can span multiple lines.

Comment: Neat, I now feel like an idiot for not checking if TODOs can span. Also, I noticed multiline todos also work in /*..*/ as long as there is a hanging indent.